# Facebook Graph API: How many facebook likes can I get for graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

How many facebook likes can I get for graph api (https://graph.facebook.com/uid/likes/) by one connection?

For example, I probably can get all facebook likes from a user who has liked 100 times.

But, can I get all facebook likes from a user who has liked 5,000 times?

Then, I guess set "paging" in response data from graph api (https://graph.facebook.com/uid/likes/).

Please tell me how many facebook likes can I get for graph api.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the pagination links that come back in the Graph API response to page through the results